# Android performing a large sqllite write in async task freezes the UI

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, asynchronous, android-asynctask

So I am writing an app that on first run needs to pull some data from the web and write it to a db table. The issue is that its crashing the UI Thread. Its running in an async task but still causing issues on the UI. I don't really care about progress or knowing when its done. Just want it to do its thing without the user really knowing.

Its not a ton of data. The JSON response is under 600kb and thats around 9,000 rows in the DB. Only takes around 30-45 seconds but I'd rather have the rest of the app be usable in that time.

Here is where I have some of the setup to build out the db in an async task.

```
public void updateDBBackground() {
    new UpdateDbTask().execute("", "", "");
}


private class UpdateDbTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        long totalSize = 0;
        open();
        String url = "someurl";

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray queuearray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                            for (int i = 0; i < queuearray.length(); i++) {
                                if (!queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("artist").isEmpty()) {
                                    insert(queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getLong("id"), queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("item1"), queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("item2"));
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    }
                });

        VolleySig.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

        return "";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

I call all this from the main activity.

```
   DBManager db = new DBManager(this);
    if (!db.checkDb()) {
        db.updateDBBackground();
    }
```

Here is the crash report data.

```
09-04 17:20:29.065 18263-18270/com.SOMEAPP I/art: Thread[3,tid=18270,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7a74799000,peer=0x12ccb160,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
09-04 17:20:29.155 18263-18270/com.SOMEAPP I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

And here is the content of traces.txt

[http://pastebin.com/traces](http://pastebin.com/2bWbGfbG)

Comment: can you please paste the crash dump also?

Comment: That's a good use case for using a Service, there's no reason your task should run inside an Activity.

Comment: Added the related crash data. I thought about using a service. Seemed a bit much for a one time thing. So its started from an activity because thats just the first thing the app does. Open it, go to the home activity.

Comment: Tried using a Service and handled my own threading in there. Still locked up the UI. I tried an Intent Service and had it do the request and add items to the DB. Even that locked up the UI.

Comment: You're using the MainActivity to initialize the DBManager. Looks like this breaks the activity lifecycle. Is your user forwarded to another activity? Though, if you moved the content to a Service, this make no sense. What is the open method for?

Comment: You shouldn't have a task here at all.  Volley takes care of your threading, you just need to add the request object to the queue on the main thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan wasn't about getting the volley call to be in the background. I know volley takes care of threading its requests. However doing a lot of sql writes upon response was crashing the UI. Thus the async call is more about handling that in the background than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was doing items in a background thread but spawning enough of them that it was causing the UI to hang.

I switched the DB from Sqllite to Realm for a few reasons and am now loading the items as show. There can sometimes be a second or two of UI lag but nothing overly significant.

```
    private void UpdateDB() {
    String url = "http://example.com&return=JSON";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        final JSONArray queuearray = response.getJSONArray("items");

                        realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
                        // Open the Realm for the UI thread.
                        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);


                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                // Add a person

                                for (int i = 0; i < queuearray.length(); i++) {

                                    try {
                                        if (!queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("value").isEmpty()) {
                                            Media media = realm.createObject(Media.class);
                                            media.setValue(queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"));
                                            media.setTitle(queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                                            media.setItemid(queuearray.getJSONObject(i).getLong("itemid"));
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        });


                    } catch (Exception e) {


                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    VolleySig.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

    realm.close();
}
```